# Which code is written better?

Tags: c#, static-code-analysis

I ran a static code analysis tool on our tool and looking at its results the code below was one of the things it was talking about:

```
    SpreadSnapshot oSnap = new SpreadSnapshot();
    using (oSnap.SetRowCol(fpSpread, row, col))
    {
        SpreadSetComboBox(fpSpread, list, displayProperty);
    }
```

So I changed it to the code below and it fixed the error that the tool was talking about:

```
    using (SpreadSnapshot oSnap = new SpreadSnapshot())
    {
        oSnap.SetRowCol(fpSpread, row, col);
        SpreadSetComboBox(fpSpread, list, displayProperty);
    }
```

So in your opinion Which style of coding do you think is more appropriate and less error-prone?

Thanks

Comment: [codereview.se] exists for questions like this.

Comment: And just what error *was* it talking about?

Comment: @KyleTrauberman: this 500K code has been converted from VB 6.0 to C# with some tools, we couldn't code review all of it again, so we are refactoring stuff like this as we see them in code.

Comment: That's fine.  I'm just saying there is a site for code reviews that you should use, as they are considered off topic on [SO].

Comment: Are those two examples doing the same thing? It looks like, in the first, the result of SetRowCol is disposed. In the second, oSnap is disposed.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman : Oh, ok, thanks, I didn't notice about it, there is actually a code review website, nice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two mean completely different things, unless `SetRowCol` returns `this` at the end.  In the first, you're disposing the results of `SetRowCol`.  In the second, you're disposing the `SpreadSnapshot`.

If both are disposable, you should do a using for both:

```
using (SpreadSnapshot oSnap = new SpreadSnapshot())
using (oSnap.SetRowCol(fpSpread, row, col))
{
    SpreadSetComboBox(fpSpread, list, displayProperty);
}
```

Comment: correct, it was returning "this", so the first code is still correct. right?

Answer (score 6):

The latter - it ensures that you don't end up using `oSnap` *after* the `using` statement.

Aside from anything else, it would be pretty odd for `SetRowCol` to return something disposable... what would that even mean?

Comment: I'm using the using statement when I'm doing linq-to-sql (using DataContext....). What's the difference between using a using statement and instantiating an object?

Comment: @frenchie: That's too big a question to easily answer in comments, but it should be covered in any good introductory C# book. I *strongly* suggest you read up on the using statement before continuing...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks Jon, does the first coding style will cause memory leaks too?

Comment: ok, I will. Does it affect performance or just pattern/readability?

Comment: @frenchie: It affects automatically disposing of resources. The first form will leak (probably temporarily) if the object has resources which need disposing and `SetRowCol` throws an exception.

Comment: got it, in IL code, it transforms into a try/catch construct and make the code "safer". Found this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6564/Understanding-the-using-statement-in-C

Comment: @frenchie: try/finally, not try/catch.